# Build WebService Based on XSD (According to IFX Protocol)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xml, protocols

I was given a task to build a web service based on [IFX Standard](http://www.ifxforum.org/standards/) XSD file.

I have got the listed files.
[image]

What I've done so far is - used xsd.exe (.net tool) and generated classes based on xsd.
Here is what it looks like (notice the scroll size):

[image]

For the test scenario I have applied [DataMember] attribute to the class member. And that's the way I intend exchange class objects.

Is this a normal approach? I have to apply attributes to hundreds of classes by hand
and I guess it'll be nightmare to maintain the code.

Comment: `DataContract` and `DataMember` are optional. This is a WCF-specific question though, and should be on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

[XSD2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) supports the `DataContract` and `Datamember` attributes.